# SQL query to get count of each fileid entry in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a table like given below, the table name is `tag`.

```
id fileid 
== ======
 1   1
 2   2
 3   2
 4   2
 5   3
 6   3
 7   3
```

I need to find the number of occurrences of each `fileId`. So the output need to be something like this:

```
fileId count
====== =====
  1      1
  2      3
  3      3
```

Can somebody help me with writing this MySQL query?

Comment: This might not be the best question in the world, but why the downvote? I can see a problem, and a specific question with data around it to help. SO can be a little too harsh sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    SELECT fieldId, COUNT(Id) AS count FROM tag GROUP BY fieldId
```

Comment: @damodar what is the fault in the answer?? will u describe me??

Comment: @Damodar: How would *you* improve this answer? It looks correct to me.

Comment: @Damodar, this is the optimized answer using `count(val)` ;                   [see this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/) so   `count(*) counts NULLs and count(column) does not`

Comment: @dEcho, that's a common fallacy that it's slower, especially when the column is probably not null (as an ID would be). In fact, that link you reference has `count(*)` running _faster_ than `count(val)`. I can't think why this would be downvoted however other than the (innocent) mistake of using the wrong column name, which would be a bit harsh.

Comment: @diEcho : mistake you have done here is "using the wrong column name" also y cannt use count (1) which is more efficient ...

Comment: @damodar have you ever read the  mysql performance blog? there is no difference using `count(*)` or `count(val)`, i use `count(val)` just for being more clear.

Comment: @diEcho : you are worng count(*) will raverse entire records set while searching but count(1) will traverse till featched value and stop seraching....

Comment: @diEcho : you are agian completely mistaken, count(1) means not count(val) , please check this link http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2007/01/count1-vs-count-any-difference/

Comment: @damodar read the comments of the given link : `COUNT(*) is converted to COUNT(1) within the parser, therefore very early in the query execution sequence.`

Comment: @diEcho : I experienced myself in regarding performance wise count(1) is more efficient that count(*) while profiling

Comment: @damodar, that's your point of view and that is not general..here are mysql guru. they know better them me & you.

Comment: @diEcho : I think we can stop arguing here, even the link what i have given is also well experienced in mysql... I pointed this answer to moderators , let they take decission. Iam nothing here :)

Answer (score 4):

That would be:

```
select fileId, count(*)
from tag
group by fileId
order by fileId
```

The `group by` will aggregate rows with the same `fileId` value and the `count(*)` will count those rows for each.

Comment: Thanx, i solved it, here's my query SELECT DISTINCT `fileId` AS id, Count( id ) AS count
FROM `Tag`
GROUP BY `fileId`
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: The "order by" is redundant, is it not?

Comment: @Kumaripaba: Why `DISTINCT`? Why `DESC LIMIT 0 , 30`? And why not accept a perfectly good answer?

Comment: @Grim, without the `order by`, the DBMS is free to order the rows as it sees fit, even with grouping.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - This answer didn't work because of missing DISTINCT. Without DISTINCT it just gives the total number of fileids, not the count of each type of file id.